# Encode youtube live stream to UDP out using youtube-dl and ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, live-streaming, youtube-dl

I am trying to encode **youtube live stream** to **UDP** destination using youtube-dl and ffmpeg with below command

```
youtube-dl -f best --buffer-size 2M -o - "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkUvWJiTf9A" | ffmpeg -re -f mp4 -i pipe:0 -codec copy -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.107:1234?pkt_size=1316
```

But its not working, its just downloading ts segments of that live stream.
When I am trying with **video of youtube** its working fine with below commands

```
youtube-dl -f best --buffer-size 2M -o - "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snDI6AaL04g" | ffmpeg -re -f mp4 -i pipe:0 -codec copy -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.107:1234?pkt_size=1316
```

Any help or suggestion appreciated.

Comment: If you found a solution you can add it as an answer in the box below and clicking "Post Your Answer" instead of adding it to your question. Then other users can upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it solved using below command using Streamlink with ffmpeg. sharing so anyone needed can refer that.

```
streamlink --hls-segment-threads 10 --ringbuffer-size 10M https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NMre6IAAAiU 140p,worst --stdout | ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -codec copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts udp://192.168.2.7:1234?pkt_size=1316
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do all of this anymore you can just use yt-dlp the latest project based on youtube-dl you can use this command in bash or you can translate this in your preferred language.

```
Link=$(yt-dlp -g yoururl)

ffmpeg -f hls -i $Link -f mpegts udp://localhost:8888
```

Getting the latest yt-dlp is crucial python3 pip always has the latest builds

```
pip3 install yt-dlp
```

Hope this helps someone